# Подсветить label при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, есть несколько лейблов:

```
<label for="CoinVal_1">1</label>
<label for="CoinVal_2">2</label>
<label for="CoinVal_3">3</label>
```

Как сделать подчеркивание лейбла, на который был произведен клик, и подчеркнуть другой, если кликнули на другой лейбл, но не убирать подчеркивание, если клик был сделан по любому другому элементу на странице?

Answer (score 1):

```js
  let allLabel = document.querySelectorAll('label');

  allLabel.forEach(value => {
    value.addEventListener('click', e => {
      drop();
      e.target.classList.add('border');
    });
  });

  function drop(){
    allLabel.forEach(value => {
      value.classList.remove('border')
    });
  }
```

```css
  .border {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black; /* Параметры линии под текстом */
  }
```

```html
  <label for="CoinVal_1" class="label">1</label>
  <label for="CoinVal_2" class="label">2</label>
  <label for="CoinVal_3" class="label">3</label>
```

Comment: прошу прощения, не могли бы сделать удаление выделений с элемента, если был кликнут другой элемент? По глупости не указал это в вопросе